# onsubmit JS script does not redirect to correct location

Tags: javascript, html

I want to redirect when a form is submitted using the following code:

```
<form onsubmit="window.location.href = '/join_game';" id='info'>
    <textarea id='player_name'></textarea>
    <button type='submit'><p>Join Game!</button>
</form>
```

the starting href value:  http://localhost:5000/

I want this value:  http://localhost:5000/join_game

the value that I get:  http://localhost:5000/?

Why do I get that last url?  If I type the exact same command into my browser's dev console, it works just fine.  I've tried location.replace and location.assign, neither doing anything different.  I'm pretty new to using JS with HTML, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does this need to be done throw javascript or you can just submit the form to action page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using javascript, why don't you just use the good ol' `action` attribute of the `form` element like so:

and quick note: you have a paragraph element inside your button but you did not close it, I'm just going to remove it since you can directly put text inside the button.

```
<form action='/join_game' id='info'>
    <textarea id='player_name'></textarea>
    <button type='submit'>Join Game!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That's great!  My HTML inexperience surely shows.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with javascript you need to stop the submit of the form with `return false;`

```
<form onsubmit="window.location.href='/join_game';return false;" id='info'>
    <textarea id='player_name'></textarea>
    <button type='submit'>Join Game!</button>
</form>
```

`window.location.href='/join_game';` -> you change the location 
`return false;` - here you stop the refresh of the page that would occur with the form submit
It would be great if you put `name` attribute for your `<textarea>`, and send this like @Zack VT said, throw form action. When you assign a `name` to `<textarea>`, you can access in your for example PHP file with `$_POST['name']`
 (example: `<textarea id='player_name' name='player_name'></textarea>` then in PHP file you can access what user was entered in `<textarea>` with `$_POST['player-name']`)

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer!  That helps with understanding the underlying reasons for the problem.